# How to set an initial script to be loaded at the start of LXC interactive session?

Tags: bash, lxc

I'd like to have my favourite aliases and PS1 when starting an interactive LXD session by

```
lxc exec my-container -- su -l
```

I've placed`.bashrc` file in the `$HOME` directory (which is `/home/root`), but it didn't work.

As `/bin/sh` in my container does not point to `/bin/bash`, I've also tried the command `lxc exec my-container -- /bin/bash` , but if failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

It required creating `/root` directory and placing my `.bashrc` there